# Flutter App Crashing in TestFlight but works on Simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, testflight

Been working on a flutter app. Everything is fine and we can debug on simulators and devices, both iOS and Android. Our Android app builds fine and the APK is up in the Play Store. The iOS app on the other hand doesn't like to be deployed via TestFlight. Building an archive, uploading to
AppStore distributing the app through TestFlight we see the app crash immediately on startup.

```
Incident Identifier: A2957531-E65F-4D12-8BBD-7E2F81D3E421
Hardware Model:      iPhone13,2
Process:             Runner [28250]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/81207991-AD48-47CF-838B-65B6A07B6739/Runner.app/Runner
Identifier:          com.something.someapp
Version:             7 (1.5.1)
AppStoreTools:       12E262
AppVariant:          1:iPhone13,2:14
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.something.someapp[3642]


Date/Time:           2021-06-28 22:26:52.5039 +0300
Launch Time:         2021-06-28 22:26:52.3731 +0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.3 (18C66)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    1.31.03-5
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b996c414 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d73c6b40 pthread_kill + 272 (pthread.c:1388)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000194f92b74 abort + 104 (abort.c:110)
3   Flutter                         0x00000001039768e0 0x103698000 + 3008736
4   Flutter                         0x0000000103976a10 0x103698000 + 3009040
5   Flutter                         0x0000000103b6920c 0x103698000 + 5050892
6   Flutter                         0x00000001039e5914 0x103698000 + 3463444
7   Flutter                         0x00000001036a60ec 0x103698000 + 57580
8   Flutter                         0x00000001036bb134 0x103698000 + 143668
9   Flutter                         0x00000001036baf70 0x103698000 + 143216
10  UIKitCore                       0x000000018e1b5fa4 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2288 (UINib.m:389)
11  UIKitCore                       0x000000018e72dd9c -[UIStoryboard __reallyInstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 284 (UIStoryboard.m:233)
12  UIKitCore                       0x000000018e72dc34 -[UIStoryboard _instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 128 (UIStoryboard.m:212)
13  UIKitCore                       0x000000018e5ae068 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 184 (UIApplication.m:4396)
14  UIKitCore                       0x000000018e5ae59c -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 276 (UIApplication.m:0)
15  UIKitCore                       0x000000018e5accec -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 996 (UIApplication.m:4155)
16  UIKitCore                       0x000000018dc02f20 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 152 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:436)
17  UIKitCore                       0x000000018e171054 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 112 (_UISceneLifecycleState.m:109)
18  UIKitCore                       0x000000018dc03ab8 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 224 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:549)
19  UIKitCore                       0x000000018dc034c0 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 300 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:498)
20  UIKitCore                       0x000000018dc038c8 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 768 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:548)
21  UIKitCore                       0x000000018dc03104 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 340 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:454)
22  UIKitCore                       0x000000018dc0b650 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block... + 196 (_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:72)
23  UIKitCore                       0x000000018e07d6c4 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 892 (BSAnimationSettings+UIKit.m:50)
24  UIKitCore                       0x000000018e18977c _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 272 (_UISceneSettingsDiffAction.m:23)
25  UIKitCore                       0x000000018dc0b348 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 384 (_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:57)
26  UIKitCore                       0x000000018da3284c __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 776 (UIScene.m:1413)
27  UIKitCore                       0x000000018da311c0 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 256 (UIScene.m:1134)
28  UIKitCore                       0x000000018da32474 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 248 (UIScene.m:1380)
29  UIKitCore                       0x000000018e5aaf84 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 572 (UIApplication.m:3681)
30  UIKitCore                       0x000000018e0a6ef0 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 388 (UIApplicationSceneClientAgent.m:45)
31  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019b8b63bc -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 432 (FBSScene.m:435)
32  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019b8e1d04 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.200 + 128 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:365)
33  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019b8c54a0 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 240 (FBSWorkspace.m:355)
34  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019b8e19c8 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 372 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:364)
35  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b7e9db0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
36  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b7ed738 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 268 (queue.c:468)
37  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019b90a250 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48 (FBSSerialQueue.m:184)
38  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019b909ee0 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 448 (FBSSerialQueue.m:227)
39  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019b90a434 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 32 (FBSSerialQueue.m:258)
40  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bb7176c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1967)
41  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bb71668 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208 (CFRunLoop.c:2011)
42  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bb70960 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268 (CFRunLoop.c:2048)
43  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bb6aa8c __CFRunLoopRun + 824 (CFRunLoop.c:2925)
44  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bb6a21c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
45  GraphicsServices                0x00000001a366e784 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2259)
46  UIKitCore                       0x000000018e5a8fe0 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072 (UIApplication.m:3253)
47  UIKitCore                       0x000000018e5ae854 UIApplicationMain + 168 (UIApplication.m:4707)
48  Runner                          0x000000010292ea2c main + 64 (AppDelegate.swift:8)
49  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018b82a6b0 start + 4
```

Comment: have you found the solution for this ?

Comment: Firebase settings in appdelegate file is causing this. I fixed checking google maps key, firabase initializing code and package versions.

Comment: Anyone can explain how to slove this issue ?